# Emacs Regex Capture+Replace: (abc (:key map)) -> (abc (-> map :key str))

Tags: emacs, regex

I have a bunch of (clojure) code that looks like this:

```
(content (:some-key some-map))
```

I want this code to become:

```
(content (-> some-map :some-key str))
```

I tried:

```
(content (\(:[-a-z].*\) \([-a-z].*\)))
```

For the search part, and:

```
(content (-> \2 \1 str))
```

For the replace part, but it found no matches. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(content (\(:[-a-z]+\) \([-a-z]+\)))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My mistake. I was actually doing a non-regex replace when I thought I was doing a regex replace. Sorry for the mistake.